# Sometimes sudden shutdown after serverstart followed by automatic restart after about 5 Minutes

Tags: debian, shutdown, asus, wake-on-lan

I wake up my homeserver via wake on lan. Most of the times, after about 45 seconds I can hook into the machine with ssh. That is perfectly fine. It appears, that when the last log in was a longer time ago (a couple of hours), I can not access the server right away after about 45 seconds. I have to wait about 5 more minutes to be able to get in. I do not find any hints in /var/log/.
Here is what I can observe:

```
ME@Laptop:~$ date
Wed 29 Dec 2021 07:04:57 PM CET

ME@Laptop:~$ wakeonlan 17:F2:42:54:04:A6
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 17:F2:42:54:04:A6

ME@Laptop:~$ ping 192.168.0.201
PING 192.168.0.201 (192.168.0.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
...
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=35 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=36 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=38 ttl=64 time=8.96 ms       <--- There it is shortly
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=78 Destination Host Unreachable         <--- ... and gone!
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=79 Destination Host Unreachable
...
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=361 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=362 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=363 ttl=64 time=1352 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=364 ttl=64 time=329 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=389 ttl=64 time=2.03 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=390 ttl=64 time=4.15 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.201 ping statistics ---
390 packets transmitted, 29 received, +273 errors, 92.5641% packet loss, time 1100ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.714/62.398/1352.149/250.840 ms, pipe 4

ME@Laptop:~$ ssh S02
ME@s02's password: 
Linux S02 4.19.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Dec 29 11:28:52 2021 from 2001:4dd7:2e8c:0:61de:9f:e12f:ba74

ME@Server:~$ sudo shutdown now
[sudo] Passwort für ME: 
Connection to s02 closed by remote host.
Connection to s02 closed.

ME@Laptop:~$ ping 192.168.0.201
PING 192.168.0.201 (192.168.0.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.201 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 262ms

ME@Laptop:~$ date
Wed 29 Dec 2021 07:12:53 PM CET

ME@Laptop:~$ wakeonlan 17:F2:42:54:04:A6
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 17:F2:42:54:04:A6

ME@Laptop:~$ ping 192.168.0.201
PING 192.168.0.201 (192.168.0.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
...
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=38 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.22 icmp_seq=39 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=40 ttl=64 time=493 ms          <--- There it is and it stays on!!!
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=41 ttl=64 time=1.67 ms
...
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=264 ttl=64 time=2.09 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.201: icmp_seq=265 ttl=64 time=2.82 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.201 ping statistics ---
265 packets transmitted, 226 received, +39 errors, 14.717% packet loss, time 512ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.631/5.289/493.460/32.711 ms, pipe 4

ME@Laptop:~$ date
```

How is it to explain that my system dies suddenly. How is it to explain that it restarts itself magically after about 5 more minutes? Where can I possibly look to find out what is happening? I strongly assume, that it is not a temperature problem, since it only happens, when I start the machine cold after some hours. By shutting down manually and starting right after the unwanted restart there seems to be no problem any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find out, what was wrong. It does not have to do anything directly with the OS debian. It is a hardware issue - I will try to add better tags for this post - probably it might help somebody then. This post belongs into another forum - that I can not change.

My Asus Motherboard P8P67-M Pro apparently had problems with the RAM memory modules. The board has a MemOK!-switch which I simply had to activate and then save some gathered knowledge of the memory modules to BIOS. Before the MemOK! activation the DRAM LED was red when starting up followed by an abrupt shutdown after start-up and a mystical reboot after a couple of minutes. After the automatic reboot, everything seemed fine. The Motherboard seemed to be working as it should for the next manual shutdowns and power-ups as if the motherboard remembered that it had to find a workaround for memory module communication. After some hours in power-off, the problem reoccured though, as if the motherboard forgot about the workaround. Using Mem-OK! manually, seems to make the board remember permanently. Unfortunately, unplugging the computer from electricity needs a manual press of the MemOK!-switch again.
So my advice for everybody with sudden automatic restarts of computers with ASUS motherboards would be to check the DRAM LED und eventually make the board learn manually with the MemOK!-switch, if present. By the way, yes, I updated the BIOS before to the latest version and placed a fresh battery in the motherboard. In my special case I needed to set up my OS again - UEFI did not let me select my installed debian after the BIOS update. The ASUS support had no workaround other then reinstalling the OS. Be careful updating BIOS - at best do not update at all;-) Hope this helps somebody.